# How do i get value in the enum stored in index xyz in C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
enum testing{a,b,c};
testing eg;
int xyz = 1;
```

How do i get value "b" using xyz variable?
something like eg(xyz)...

Answer (score 3):

You could just:

```
eg = static_cast<testing>(xyz);
```

Comment: It still gives xyz's int value i.e.1 <br/>
    eg = static_cast<testing>(xyz); <br/>
    cout<<eg;  <br/>
output is "1". not "b"

Comment: Oh. But that's how enums work. the value of b in your enum is 1 (a is 0 and c is 2). If you want to print the `name` of the enum constant I think you have to overload the << operator